# How to test the connection between my computer and google cloud instance?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, telnet

I am currently working on a project to make a server with cassandra,
the problem is that I can't connect my api to my cassandra server. The api is not on the same server as cassandra.

To check that the connection with the google server, I made a telnet. But this one returns me an error message.

This is the error return the telnet :
[image]
and this is my google cloud configuration
[image]
and to finish the fire wall configuration

[image]

I have added a call log to my ironclad rule, and we can see that the server is receiving the call, so I don't understand why the telnet is returning an error.

Comment: Run this on your server to gather more info netstat -tulpn

Comment: Are you able to join the cassandra port (9042) from the VM itself? Just to check if the process is correctly running and listening. Or use the danyL command.

Comment: I know that the server respects the request but why is the answer negative? @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: There are many possibilities. There is something between you and the servers. That's why, try to validate step by step. First the program running on the VM: is it listen in 0.0.0.0 or in localhost (127.0.0.1). Then the communication: open the ICMP on your network tag and try to ping your VM: from your computer and from Cloud Shell. If from Cloud Shell and not your computer, you have a firewall on your computer/network side.

Comment: Did your issue get resolved, if not, try Guillaume's suggestion and update.